# Correct way to add more views to adapter

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, admob, adapter

I am trying to fix a little problem that is when I use native ads every 6 items in adapter (Shown below) and I retrieve the data from firebase and the problem is that there is an post missing every 6 posts and that is because It replaces by the ads.

Here's my code to retrieve posts from firebase:

```
mDatabasePosts.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                            model_class value = dataSnapshot2.getValue(model_class.class);

                            //I think the solution should be here

                            mPosts_List.add(value);

                            //I think the solution should be here

                            mPosts_Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                    @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}});
```

And here's my adapter:

```
@Override public int getItemCount() {
    return mPosts_List.size();
}

@Override public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0){return Head_View;}

    else if (position % 6 == 0){return Ads_View;}

    return Posts_View;
}

@Override public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case Head_View:
            View HEADER_VIEW = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.head_handler_view, viewGroup, false);
            return new HEAD_View_Holder(HEADER_VIEW);

        case Posts_View:
            View POSTS_VIEW = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.posts_handler_view, viewGroup, false);
            return new posts_handler(POSTS_VIEW);

        case Ads_View:default:View AD_VIEW = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.admob_handler_view, viewGroup, false);
            return new admob_handler(AD_VIEW);}
}


@Override public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
    switch (viewType) {
        case Head_View:final HEAD_View_Holder User_Holder = (HEAD_View_Holder) holder;

            User_Holder.add_post_handler(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()));break;

        case Posts_View:
            posts_handler_b Normal_Holder = (posts_handler_b) holder;

            retrieve_data model = mPosts_List.get(position);Normal_Holder.Card_View_Time(model.getH());
            Normal_Holder.Card_View_Handler(model.getK(),position);break;

        case Ads_View:default:
            admob_handler Ads_Holder = (admob_handler) holder;

            Ads_Holder.Show_ADS();
  }
}
```

**So please can any body give me the solution like duplicating posts every 6 positions to show them or if there's simple solution .. So please help me brothers.**

Comment: Do you want an ads for each 6 normal items or an ads for each 5 normal items ? in the first case you should use position % 7 == 0

Comment: I need an ads for each 5 items ..

Comment: Any help brothers to solve this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be that when you bind your post views, you get data with the given position.

You should decrement index to not jump position in your data array corresponding to your ad views on every six items.

Something like

```
case Posts_View:
        posts_handler_b Normal_Holder = (posts_handler_b) holder;

        retrieve_data model = mPosts_List.get(position - (position / 6) - 1);
        Normal_Holder.Card_View_Time(model.getH());
        Normal_Holder.Card_View_Handler(model.getK(),position);break;
```

Comment: And how can I make it, any coding @smora please??

Comment: See my update. If you dont see where to change this, add your bind view method in your original post. You're certainly get your data from an array or a list at one moment to bind your view, this is where to do it.

Comment: Sorry @smora for disturbing you, but I am actually new to development but can you edit my adapter above to get fully answer.

Comment: yeah but where is your onBindViewHolder method ?

Comment: I'll edit post now, you can check the updated question now.

Comment: It looks it will work but there's also problem that is the last 2 posts are missing??

Comment: Have you update getItemCount() method like @EmreAkturk propose in his answer ?

Comment: Nope .. because @EmreAkturk method crashes my app when I scroll to bottom.

Comment: Now with the onBindViewHolder fix it should be ok.

Comment: Ok let me try .. still crashes my app when scroll to bottom tilling me "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 13, Size: 13".

Comment: @Emre is right, you should add -1 to index if header is present like you've done. Ive fixed my answer.

Comment: Thanks you @smora for helping me, don't care about point, the big thing that you have help man who was despair.

Comment: No problem, happy that you find the way to solve this ! Just an advice, take time to read about java/android naming code rules ;)

Comment: After rechecking the correct answer was from @smroa firstly.

Comment: thks for that :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment your item count for each adds.

```
@Override public int getItemCount() {
   return mPosts_List.isEmpty() ? 0 : mPosts_List.size() + (mPosts_List.size() / 6) + 1;
}
```

Also added +1 if your head view not representing your data.

**UPDATE**

```
@Override public retrieve_data getItemAtPosition(int position) {
   return mPost_List.get(position - (position / 6) - 1)
}
```

And you need to use this method in **onBindHolder** to retrive data.

```
retrieve_data model = mPosts_List.get(position)
```

Replace with

```
retrieve_data model = getItemAtPosition(position)
```

Comment: Sorry @Emre Aktürk, that doesn't work still ads replace the posts views, and the app crash when scroll to bottom of recycler??

Comment: Probably IndexOutOfBounds exceptions occurs because we are trying to get an item with index that oversize it.

Comment: And where I can use the above method, make also in mind that I also have an header??

Comment: In OnBindHolder, instead of mPosts_List.get(position) you can replace it with getItemAtPosition(position)

Comment: Ok I got it, but should I use another method??

Comment: Thanks @Emre Aktürk for giving me from your time and I am not believing that I am going to fix that issue.. THANKS EVERYBODY. COOOOOOOOL

Comment: After rechecking the correct answer was from @smroa firstly.

Comment: Thank you @Emre Aktürk for your kindnes (;.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you do not account for the difference you create in the `position` given by `onBindViewHolder()` by inserting views between the items in your `mPosts_List`.

The *simplest* way to fix this would be to adjust the `position` value when you have a `Posts_View` view type.

```
case Post_View:
    int adjustedPosition = position - (position / 6) - 1
```

Comment: i am not sure but i think we need to decrement 1 for header.

Comment: Ok @Emre Aktürk, let me try but should I use your getItemCount() method above??

Comment: @EmreAktürk Ah, you are absolutely right; fixed it.